# Django 1.5: tests for user registration, Errors/Fails for Signals/Outbox

Tags: django, testing, signals, django-registration

I'm working on a test suite for a Django (1.5) application.  I'm using version 0.8 of the Django-Registrations package, and I was getting a ton of Test Errors all ending with `IntegrityError: auth_user.first_name may not be NULL`.  Each of these errors seemed to happen as a result of a signal receiver I'd defined in `account/models.py`:

```
@receiver(user_registered)
def user_registered_handler(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    user.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
    user.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
    profile = user.get_profile()
    profile.about = request.POST.get('about')
    profile.address = request.POST.get('address')
    ... etc.
    user.save()
    profile.save()
```

Just to see, I commented this out, and ran the tests again. This eliminated all of these errors, but now I get 5 fails, all complaining about the length of mail.outbox being 0, instead of 1 or 2 or whatever.

[Here's the github repo for the project.](https://github.com/AnthonyBRoberts/fcclincoln)

[Here's a link to the tests for django-registrations](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/2d6fcc0c55d0c63d5e506b59e32cad9329963509/registration/tests/?at=v0.8)

If anyone can help me understand why this happens, that would be awesome. If you feel like suggesting a path forward, that would be even more awesome.

Thanks,